# needing to remove single characters and numbers python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, punctuation, email-spam

```
def removePunctuation(emails):
     cleanedEmails = [email.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for email in emails]
     return cleanedEmails
```

above the code can be seen. I am needing to remove single characters and numbers from emails. This is to be used for email spam classification. I previously used (along these lines can't remember exact code). The code itself already removes punctuation however due to how the punctuation is removed this is why I am having difficulty with the removal of single chars and numbers.

```py
''.join(I for I in emails if i.isaplha() and I == 1)
```

however this I can't get to work due to the code changing to translate etc

Comment: Can you give some examples? What will the input and what will be the output?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and output?

Comment: The input are txt files of emails. The output should be just words but there are numbers and single characters present which I need to remove

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to understand this question as best as I could, I think this is correct, adjust Line 2 as necessary.

```
def removePunctuation(emails):
    punctuation = '!"£$%^&*()'
    cleanedEmails = [email.translate(str.maketrans('', '', punctuation)) for email in emails]
    return cleanedEmails
```

Comment: It already removes the punctuation. I need to remove single characters and numbers however the code I put as a single line doesn’t work with the punctuation code

Comment: What do you mean by "single characters"?

Comment: I just mean single letters like a d h etc rather than whole words

Comment: Change line 2 in my code to punctuation = '!"£$%^&*()adh' then.

Comment: I was just giving an example it’s all single characters in the alphabet and numbers

Comment: punctuation = '!"£$%^&*()abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890'